Is this a wrong approach to replacing placeholders in a word document with data from a database?
I am trying to replace placeholders in a template word document with data loaded from a database. However, a new document is created in the location that I specified in the code but with only place holders and no real data from the database. here is my code;
def generate(request):
    """View function for the generate page."""
    if request.method == "POST":
        account_number = request.POST.get("account_number")
        try:
            # Query the database to get account data
            account = Client_Account.objects.get(ACCTNUM=account_number)
        except Client_Account.DoesNotExist:
            error_message = "Client account not found."
            return render(
                request, "core/generate.html", {"error_message": error_message}
            )

        try:
            templatepath = "C:\Equity\mcf\mcf\core\wordtemplate\emplate.docx"
            document = Document(templatepath)
            # account2 = Client_Form_Info.objects.get(ACCTNUM=account_number)
            for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
                if "{{account_name}}" in paragraph.text:
                    paragraph.text = Client_Account.ACCT_NAME
                output_directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "outputs")
                output_filename = f"output_{account.ACCT_NAME}.docx"
                output_file_path = os.path.join(output_directory, output_filename)
                document.save(output_file_path)
                return redirect("success")

            else:
                return HttpResponse("Failed to generate document", status=500)
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {e}", status=500)
    else:
        return render(request, "core/generate.html")

What could be wrong?
